# To prove or disprove $abc=1$ $\implies$ $ \sqrt {a^4+a^2b^2+b^4}+\sqrt {b^4+b^2c^2+c^4}+\sqrt {c^4+c^2a^2+a^4} > \dfrac92$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c$ be positive real numbers such that $abc=1$ , then is it true that

$ \sqrt {a^4+a^2b^2+b^4}+\sqrt {b^4+b^2c^2+c^4}+\sqrt {c^4+c^2a^2+a^4} > \dfrac92$ ?

Comment: That escalated quickly.

Comment: Hein? 2^(3/4)=1.68179283051...
so just take a=b=c=2^0.25

Comment: why did you change now??

Answer (score 6):

With the hope that the problem remains unchanged;

---

First see that:
$$
\sqrt{a^4+a^2b^2+b^4}\geq \sqrt 3ab
$$
Hence:
$$
\sqrt {a^4+a^2b^2+b^4}+\sqrt {b^4+b^2c^2+c^4}+\sqrt {c^4+c^2a^2+a^4}\\\geq \sqrt 3(ab+bc+ac)\geq 3\sqrt 3> \dfrac92
$$

Comment: Hope is a good thing.

Comment: So much nicer than what I got using Lagrange Multipliers, which does indeed agree that the LHS is minimized when $a = b = c = 1$, which leads to a minimum value of the LHS of $3\sqrt{3}$.  That being said, very nice. +1, of course.